# Break out of javascript nested async.each loop but continue main loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, asynchronous, async.js

I have an array of arrays of objects called recipesArray.

```
recipesArray = [  [{name = "the recipe name", url = "http://recipeurl.com"},
                   {name = "the other neame", url = "http://adifferenturl.com"},
                   {name = "another recipe", url = "http://anotherurl.com"}],

                   [{name = "the recipe name", url = "http://recipeurl.com"},
                   {name = "the other neame", url = "http://adifferenturl.com"},
                   {name = "another recipe", url = "http://anotherurl.com"}],

                   [{name = "the recipe name", url = "http://recipeurl.com"},
                   {name = "the other neame", url = "http://adifferenturl.com"},
                   {name = "another recipe", url = "http://anotherurl.com"}] ]
```

I want to break out of this nested async.each loop, but continue the main async.each loop.

```
// main async.each
async.each(recipes, function(subArray, callback1) {
   // nested async.each
   async.each(subArray, function(theCurrentRecipe, callback2) {
      checkHREFS(theCurrentRecipe, function(thisRecipe) {
         if ('i have a conditional here') {
            // break out of this nested async.each, 
            // but continue the main async.each.
         } else {
            // continue
         }
         callback2();
      });
   }, callback1);
}, function(err) {
if (err) {
   return console.error(err);

   // success, all recipes iterated
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way might be to modify the final callback for the inner each() to check for an Error object with a special property that indicates you're breaking out early and that it's not a real error. Then inside your conditional, pass an Error object, with that property set, to the callback.

Example:

```
// main async.each
async.each(recipes, function(subArray, callback1) {
  // nested async.each
  async.each(subArray, function(theCurrentRecipe, callback2) {
    checkHREFS(theCurrentRecipe, function(thisRecipe) {
      if ('i have a conditional here') {
        // break out of this nested async.each, 
        // but continue the main async.each.
        var fakeErr = new Error();
        fakeErr.break = true;
        return callback2(fakeErr);
      }
      // continue
      callback2();
    });
  }, function(err) {
    if (err && err.break)
      callback1();
    else
      callback1(err);
  });
}, function(err) {
  if (err)
    return console.error(err);

  // success, all recipes iterated
});
```

Comment: Although I'm still wondering if there's a better way than to fake an error.

Comment: Not currently with the `async` module, I actually use this pattern when I need to break early with `async` module methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
// inner async.each (simplificated)
  async.each(subArray, function(theCurrentRecipe, callback2) {
    checkHREFS(theCurrentRecipe, function(thisRecipe) {
      if ('i have a conditional here') {
        // going to break out of this nested async.each
        return callback2({flag:true}); // It doesn't have to be an "new Error()" ;-)
      }
      // continue
      callback2();
    });
  }, function(msg) {
    if (msg && msg.flag) // Here CHECK THE FLAG
      callback1(); // all good!... we brake out of the loop!
    else
      callback1(msg); // process possible ERROR.
  });
```