# How to break inner async loop in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

please see this code why the inner loop is not breaking.
I want to push in new array only if the inner loop condition satisfies
and that should break the iteration of the inner loop but the outer loop should iterate as usual.

[Inspired from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23583723/4976968)

Here is my code :

```
var rows = [ RowDataPacket {
                                    id: 1,
                                    title: 'this is jg case',
                                    description: 'this is reply to jg case',
                                    type: 2,
                                    created: Thu Mar 03 2016 12:50:20 GMT+0530 (IST),
                                    group_id: '1,8',
                                    AOI: '1,8' },
                                  RowDataPacket {
                                    id: 2,
                                    title: 'this is jg case',
                                    description: 'this is another reply to jg case',
                                    type: 1,
                                    created: Thu Mar 03 2016 12:55:01 GMT+0530 (IST),
                                    group_id: '3,9',
                                    AOI: '1,8' },
                                  RowDataPacket {
                                    id: 3,
                                    title: 'this is jg case',
                                    description: 'this is again another reply to jg case',
                                    type: 1,
                                    created: Thu Mar 03 2016 12:58:01 GMT+0530 (IST),
                                    group_id: '3,8',
                                    AOI: '1,8' }                                      
                                ];


                    var filteredRows = [];

                    async.each(rows,  function(row, callback1){
                        var eachRow = row.group_id.split(',').map(Number);
                        async.each(eachRow, function(group, callback2){

                            if(AOI.indexOf(group) !== -1){
                                filteredRows.push(row);
                                console.log(group,row);
                                var fakeErr = new Error();
                                fakeErr.break = true;
                                return callback2(fakeErr);
                            }

                            callback2();

                        },  function(err) {

                                if (err && err.break){
                                  console.log("should break the inner loop and continue for the next outer loop")
                                  callback1(); 
                                }
                                else
                                  callback1(err); 
                            });
                    },  function(err) {

                          if (err)
                            callback(err, null);

                          callback(null, filteredRows);
                    });
```

Expected Output :

```
var filteredRows = [ RowDataPacket {
                                id: 1,
                                title: 'this is jg case',
                                description: 'this is reply to jg case',
                                type: 2,
                                created: Thu Mar 03 2016 12:50:20 GMT+0530 (IST),
                                group_id: '1,8',
                                AOI: '1,8' },
                              RowDataPacket {
                                id: 3,
                                title: 'this is jg case',
                                description: 'this is again another reply to jg case',
                                type: 1,
                                created: Thu Mar 03 2016 12:58:01 GMT+0530 (IST),
                                group_id: '3,8',
                                AOI: '1,8' }                                      
                            ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your code:

```
return callback2(fakeErr);
```

You change to:

```
callback2(fakeErr);
return;
```

And you should return in here, if not, your program receives two callback

```
if (err)
    callback(err, null);
    // return here
    return;

callback(null, filteredRows);
```

Answer (score -1):

`each()` runs iterations in parallel, you can't "break the loop" (when you do, the next iteration is already running), you have to use `eachSeries()` for example to control the async flow:

```
// process rows in parallel
async.each(rows, function(row, callback1) {
  var eachRow = row.group_id.split(',').map(Number);
  // for each row, process each group one at a time so you can break the loop
  async.eachSeries(eachRow, function(group, callback2) {
    // stuff
  });
  // stuff
});
```